# Putting mobile Google into an iframe does not work

Tags: html, iframe

Behind the following link is the mobile view of Google: [Google's mobile site](http://m.google.at/search?hl=de&safe=on&q=stackoverflow).

I tried to put it in an iframe on my website, but it doesn't work.

```
<iframe id="google_search" src="http://m.google.at/search?hl=de&safe=on&q=stackoverflow" style="width: 400px; height: 600px; overflow:scroll; border: 1px solid black;"></iframe>
```

All I get is an emty iframe. Why?

Comment: IE8 claims something along the lines of "the publisher of this site has prohibited this resource to be embedded in an iframe". Must be some new security feature

Comment: hmm ... why would google not let it happen?

Comment: @helle probably for security reasons - e.g. to prevent a malicious site to have a frameset whose main page is the Google front page, but with a "log in" link to the top right (in a separate frame) that looks just like Google's.

Comment: but i can use the not mobile page in an iframe without problems :-(

Comment: @helle true. Then I don't know why they do this... Anyway, I fear there is no workaround. You'd have to build your own Start page with a search form, and link that to Google.

Comment: well ... i need it on my 404 page to show google results for the not found uri parts ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suspect that Google is sending the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header set to `deny`. This prevents the page from loading in a frame in IE8+ and newer versions of FireFox, Opera, and Chrome (the exact version numbers escape me at the moment).

This is usually done to combat ClickJacking. The IEBlog has a great article on this: [IE8 Security Part VII: ClickJacking Defenses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/27/ie8-security-part-vii-clickjacking-defenses.aspx)