# Fancybox iframe is blank

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

so i have downloaded the fancybox zip and added it to my site. when i go to the demos area, everything is working fine with the exception of the iframe. i havent edited the code in anyway. it works perfectly on their site, so im not sure why it would be any different on mine. i have searched through this site and others and have came up with nothing. again i have not edited any of the code, i simply unzipped it and pushed it to my server. any ideas?  [View Here](http://ryanfitzmedia.com/fancybox/demo/)

Comment: Many pages start blocking to iframe their site - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449017/putting-mobile-google-into-an-iframe-does-not-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a fancybox issue.

The demo file included in the fancybox download, targets the *jQuery* site for the `iframe` sample .... but today most mayor sites like *google*, *yahoo*, and others etc. (and now *jQuery* too)  don't allow themselves to be contained within iframes. I guess the demo file is outdated.

If you can place any web site within a regular `html` `iframe` (like your own or any other you create for instance), then you can open it with fancybox too. [Check this demo and see it for yourself](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/sitesOnIframe_20feb12.html) ... notice what iframes are "blank".

You can also [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808761/1055987) for reference.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i wasn't aware that you could specify a page not to be displayed within an iframe, good to know! i was able to get a local file to show up within the iframe. however, i defiantly think fancybox should update their demo, as that was a bit confusing. again thanks for your help!

Comment: please don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if you think it solved your issues or questions. thanks

Comment: Note that if we're talking YouTube videos, the "youtube.com/watch" version of the video is not able to be pulled up in an iframe while the "youtube.com/embed" version of the video is. Important to note that because it tripped me up :)

Comment: @lewiguez : is possible for you to keep using youtube's format `youtube.com/watch?v=` **IF** you add the fancybox media helper http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples ==>extended functinality==>media helper tab (not need to set `iframe` type)

Comment: @JFK Hmm. I'm still using 1.3.x. I didn't realize this existed. That's pretty cool. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @JFK Is there any ways to handle this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456427/fancybox-how-to-check-whether-a-url-can-be-loaded-or-not-in-iframe-with-fancyb

Comment: @vivek It may not be possible with javascript (forget fancybox) check http://stackoverflow.com/q/4548984/1055987 if that helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your browser's error log / console when debugging.

I get

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

when clicking the **Iframe** link.

jquery.com is obviously implementing the [X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) to prevent you loading their site in an iFrame.

### Update

Here's an extract of the headers returned from jquery.com

```
$ telnet jquery.com 80
Trying 70.32.73.125...
Connected to jquery.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: jquery.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simply, the Iframe doesn't have a valid source.

Iframe has an attribute called src (source) which is the address of the site you want to display in the inline frame; yours in that demo is linking to http://jquery.com
I don't know how Fancy box works but I daresay that isn't what you wanted!

```
<iframe class="fancybox-iframe" name="fancybox-frame1329790605687" frameborder="0" hspace="0" scrolling="auto" src="http://jquery.com"></iframe>
```

The src attribute on the main fancybox demo site links to a local page:

```
<iframe class="fancybox-iframe" name="fancybox-frame1329790726739" frameborder="0" hspace="0" scrolling="auto" src="/demo/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

Which you can see here outside of the iframe:

http://fancyapps.com/demo/iframe.html

Comment: why the downvote ? If jquery.com isn't implementing that response header then it's not a valid source.