# reCaptcha not showing in fancybox iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, fancybox, recaptcha

I've created a form which I want to open in a fancybox (iframe). To prevent bots from filling out the forms I want to use reCaptcha. For reCaptcha I'm using the ASP.net implementation, but the problem also occurs when I'm using the javascript implementation.

Now, the reCaptcha form is showing and working on the page which I want to open inside my fancybox. But when I open the page inside my fancybox, the form is visible but the reCaptcha isn't being rendered.

When I view the source of the page I only see the following:

```
<noscript>
    &lt;iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=xxxx" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0"&gt;

    &lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;input name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" type="hidden" /&gt;
```

Comment: wonder if it's because google.com can't be contained inside an iframe

Comment: @JFK, also my thought. But is it for sure it can't?

Comment: @Rob : for sure it can't check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8700754/1055987 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808761/1055987 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9372804/1055987